# How to using instafeed in magento 2 with requirejs?

Tags: requirejs

I create module to show instagram photos here my view->frontend :

```
frontend--/
    |layout--/
    |     cms_index_index.xml
    |     default.xml
    |
    |templates--/
    |     instafeed.phtml
    |
    |web--/
    |     js--/
    |        instafeed.min.js
    |        main.js 
    |
    |requirejs-config.js
```

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
"paths":
{
    "insta": "Test_Instafeed/js/instafeed.min",
    "instaMain": "Test_Instafeed/js/main",
}};
```

main.js

```
    require(["insta"], function(){
        (function ($)
        {
             var feed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'tagged',
                tagName:  'awesome',
                clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                resolution: 'low_resolution',
                limit: '32',
              });
        });
   });
   feed.run();
```

instafeed.phtml

```
<h1><?php echo $block->getTitle(); ?></h1>
<hr />
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

But I always get error :

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return e}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch

Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ()
{
    feed.run();
}
```

I'm getting confuse with this, if anybody can help me, I will appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your **folder structure**: The `requirejs-config.js` should be placed in the `web` folder, not in the `frontend` folder.

```
|web--/
|     js--/
|        instafeed.min.js
|        main.js 
|     requirejs-config.js
```

Comment: I put requirejs-config.js inside web folder, but I still get error : Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return e}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch . By the way the second error is missing.